# String regex match replace for role 'contributor' only

Tags: filters, regex

currently I'm using the below code to add `rel=nofollow` and `target=_blank` to all external links of my site's content but I would like this to happen **only** on Contributors posts. IE, Authors posts and above have no rewrite rules.

```
<?php

add_filter( 'the_content', 'cn_nf_url_parse');

function cn_nf_url_parse( $content ) {

$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>";
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    if( !empty($matches) ) {

        $srcUrl = get_option('siteurl');
        for ($i=0; $i < count($matches); $i++)
        {

            $tag = $matches[$i][0];
            $tag2 = $matches[$i][0];
            $url = $matches[$i][0];

            $noFollow = '';

            $pattern = '/target\s*=\s*"\s*_blank\s*"/';
            preg_match($pattern, $tag2, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
            if( count($match) < 1 )
                $noFollow .= ' target="_blank" ';

            $pattern = '/rel\s*=\s*"\s*[n|d]ofollow\s*"/';
            preg_match($pattern, $tag2, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
            if( count($match) < 1 )
                $noFollow .= ' rel="nofollow" ';

            $pos = strpos($url,$srcUrl);
            if ($pos === false) {
                $tag = rtrim ($tag,'>');
                $tag .= $noFollow.'>';
                $content = str_replace($tag2,$tag,$content);
            }
        }
    }
}

$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
return $content;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [`author_can()`](http://queryposts.com/function/author_can/) for that:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse105294_nofollow_author' );
function wpse105294_nofollow_author()
{
    ! author_can( $GLOBALS['post']->ID, 'edit_others_posts' )
        AND add_filter( 'the_content', 'cn_nf_url_parse');
}
```

So you only add that filter callback for authors and other roles that don't have the possibility to `edit_others_posts`. By default this is `Subscriber` and `Author`. For more info, take a look at the [Codex article about Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

### Edit

As I've lately done some stuff with the PHP HTML DOM Parser, I thought it might be better to use this one. For the easiness off things the code was mostly taken from [@Alex answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5848273/376483).

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'cn_nf_url_parse');
function wpse_105294_Content_Parser( $content )
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( $content );

    // DOMXPath() might be just too much
    $anchors = $dom->getElementByTagName( 'a' );

    foreach ( $anchors as $a )
    {
        if ( 
            ! $a->hasAttribute( 'rel' )
            OR '' === ( $rel = trim( $a->getAttribute( 'rel' ) ) )
        )
            continue;

        $rel = preg_split( '/\s+/', $rel );

        if ( in_array( 'nofollow', $rel ) )
           continue;

        $rel[] = 'nofollow';
        $anchor->setAttribute( 'rel', implode( ' ', $rel ) );
    }

    $html = '';

    // Remove `html\body` before returning
    foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'body' )->item(0)->childNodes as $el )
        $html .= $dom->saveXML( $el, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG );

    return $html;
}
```